# Stream has already been operated upon or closed in Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, exception, java-8, mockito, java-stream

I want to test a method to return a stream.

```
class Foo {
    public void getClicks(boolean somecondition) {
        Stream s1 = computeAndGetAllClicks(new Date());
        if (somecondition) {
            Stream s2 = computeAndGetAllClicks(new Date());
        }
        return Stream.concat(s1, s2);
    }

    Stream computeAndGetAllClicks(Date d) {
        // return stream
    }
}
```

Now I have written the following test for case when somecondition = true

```
    final ArgumentCaptor<Date> argumentCaptorTodayDate = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Date.class);

    doReturn(Arrays.asList(new Click.Builder().build()).stream())
    .when(fooInstance)
    .addAtlasLineItem(computeAndGetAllClicks(argumentCaptorTodayDate.capture))

   final ArgumentCaptor<Date> argumentCaptorEndDate = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Date.class);


    doReturn(Arrays.asList(new Click.Builder().build()).stream())
    .when(fooInstance)
    .addAtlasLineItem(computeAndGetAllClicks(argumentCaptorEndDate.capture))

    fooInstance.getClicks(true);
```

However I get exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed.

How do I get around it ??

Comment: Where is this stream called `s` coming from?

Comment: This `getClicks` method can never compile. Besides that, the problem is obvious. When you use Mockito to force the method to return the same stream on every invocation, it’ll break any method expecting it to return a new stream on every invocation.

Answer (score 7):

you can use thenAnswer and create new stream each time it's invoked:

```
doAnswer(invocationOnMock->Arrays.asList(new Click.Builder().build()).stream())
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Why is it not accepted as such?